# Validation working on "Edit" but not "Create" - MVC

Tags: c#, validation, model-view-controller

I currently have a data annotation validation requirement in my model but am running into a weird problem.

Basically, I am checking to make sure that the hours entered for a timesheet is a positive number. It works perfectly fine on the *Edit* view of the timesheet but when I go to *Create* a new timesheet entry it doesn't properly validate and will let the hours be negative.

Both views are using the same model so I'm puzzled why this is happening.

**Snip of Model:**

```
[Display(Name = "Hours Worked:")]
[Range(0.00, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Hours must be positive")]
public decimal LineItemHours { get; set; }
```

**Snip of Create.cshtml (Validation not working):**

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LineItemHours, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
  <div class="col-md-9">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LineItemHours, new { @class = "form-control", id = "hoursTotal" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LineItemHours, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
</div>
```

**Snip of Edit.cshtml (Validation working):**

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LineItemHours, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
  <div class="col-md-9">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LineItemHours, new { @class = "form-control", id = "hoursTotal" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LineItemHours, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
</div>
```

### UPDATE:

I ended up figuring out what was causing this issue by going over all of the JavaScript for those pages line by line. Of course it was a stupid mistake.

When clicking the "Save" button the edit page javascript for that event had:

```
if ($("form[name = 'TimeEntryEditForm']").valid()) {...}
```

While the create page javascript for that event had:

```
if ($('form').valid()) {...}
```

Changing it to

```
if ($("form[name = 'TimeEntryCreateForm']").valid()) {...}
```

solved the problem!

Thanks for everyone's help and tips!

Comment: Are the js files the same for both views? Does the create view definitely have form tags?

Comment: Can you post your controllers?  In the controllers are your checking if model is valid?

Comment: @TylerJennings the validation is done on the client side, it shouldn't allow to even submit the form..

Comment: Have you checked using the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` in both views? is the error showing on your controller or is it bypassing `ModelState.IsValid` as well

Comment: @markpsmith From a quick glance the JS files looked about the same besides a couple small changes. There's a lot in there though so I might have to go through it more thoroughly. Both views have form tags though.

@Luiso When I use the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` nothing happens on either form when trying to submit. Currently the controller is not checking the `ModelState` for either view.

Comment: @Quiver when you say nothing happens on the forms you mean that no validation took place? Can you check the `ModelState` validation as well, it should be working but just to make sure it is

Comment: @Luiso The first time nothing happened at all but now even with the unobtrusive jquery I still get the same results (validation on edit but not on create). Checking the `ModelState` on the controller does exactly what you would expect. `ModelState.IsValid` fails when the hours are negative.

Comment: Is the client side validation is not enabled in create view. Can you put code line `Html.EnableClientValidation(true);` to enable Client side validation.

Comment: @user1672994 Nothing changes after placing that in the view. Validation still fails.

Comment: @Quiver are you sure you included `jquery` and `jquery.validate` in both views? Can you post the `JS` included in those pages?